# Inter module event subscription via service in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I am facing an issue where my service is not able to call component method of its own module. Here is the scenario

**Module A**
Component A
Service A

**Module B**
Component B
Component C

- *Component A* subscribes an event of *Service A*
- *Module B* is using *Module A*
- *Service A* is exposed to *Module B* to interact with *Component A*
- Global instance of *Service A* is used in *Component B* and is working fine as it is a global instance
- When a local instance of *Service A* is created in *Component C* by injecting the *Service A* at *Component C* level, it looses the reference to the *Component A* and stops communicating.

How can we maintain the reference to *Component A* of *Module A* inside *Component C* of *Module B*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you declaring service A with its own provider in component C?

Comment: Yes, I am injecting it in providers array.

Comment: @user3710681, You should declare your `Service A` in `providers` array of module `Module A` and not list it in `providers` array of `Component C`. Then only one instance of `Service A` will be created and used across all components.

Comment: @SergeySokolov As I have mentioned
"Global instance of Service A is used in Component B and is working fine as it is a global instance."  But I need local instances at Component level in Module B

Comment: If you want two components to communicate via service you need to share the same instanse of service among them